# In the additive group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ prove that there is only one representative q for all cosets $0\le q<1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I have clearly understood the fact that the cosets would be of the form q+$\mathbb{Z}$ where $q$ lies between $0$ and $1$ and $\mathbb Z$ will be the kernel of some homomorphism but what I didn't get is that why would there be only one  representation for the coset?can someone help me to understand the intuition..

Answer (score 1):

If $q_1$ and $q_2$ belong to the same coset and $0\leqslant q_1<1$, then $q_2-q_1\in\mathbb Z$. So, if we also have $0\leqslant q_2<1$, then $q_2-q_1\in(-1,1)$. This, together with the fac that $q_2-q_1\in\mathbb Z$, implies that $q_2-q_1=0$, since $(-1,1)\cap\mathbb Z=\{0\}$.

Comment: Suppose if we take the kernel which is $Z$ consisting of {...-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...} can it not have both 1 and 0 as representative elements?

Comment: Sure we can. What has that to do with my answer?

Comment: I really didn't get the intuition behind the question.  What does it want me to show that 0 is the only representation of the kernel(it says that there is only one representation for all cosets)

Comment: No. The goal is to prove that, for each $q\in\mathbb Q$, there is only one $q'\in\mathbb Q\cap[0,1)$ such that $q+\mathbb Z=q'+\mathbb Z$?